# Make String.format("%s", arg) display null-valued arguments differently from "null"

Tags: java, string, null, string-formatting, string.format

Consider the custom `toString()` implementation of a bean:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String.format("this is %s", this.someField);
}
```

This yields `this is null` if `someField` is null.

Is there a way to override the default `null` string representation of null-valued arguments to another text, i.e., `?` **without calling explicitly `replaceAll(...)` in the `toString` method?**

**Note**: The bean inherits from a superclass that could implement `Formattable` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html) but I just don't seem to understand how to make this work.

**EDIT**: The snippet is over-simplified for the sake of example but I'm not looking for ternary operator solutions `someField==null ? "?" : someField` because:

- there can be (potentially) a great many fields involved in `toString()` so checking all fields is too cumbersome and not fluent.
- other people whom I have little control over (if any) are writing their own subclasses.
- if a method is called and returns null that would either imply calling the method twice or declaring a local variable.

Rather, can anything be done using the `Formattable` interface or having some custom `Formatter` (which is `final` btw.)?

Comment: I would do `String.format("this is %s", this.someField==null?"?":this.someField);`

Comment: Or with Guava : `String.format("this is %s", Objects.firstNotNull(this.someField, "?"));`

Comment: I always think fondly of `firstNotNull`, esp. similar implementations some SQL dialects, but Guava is too heavy a dependence and belongs more to the dependencies a Utils class than that of a pojo, imo.

Comment: @VH-NZZ There are some great solutions. Sure you can't choose one to accept?

Comment: @KimKern Most, if not all, somehow address the issue and ultimately produce a result compatible with the question, albeit at some expense. That being said, I objectively can't assert that I can pick _one_ answer as truly superior, hence: no, at this stage I'm afraid I can't.

Answer (score 63):

With java 8 you can now use Optional class for this:

```
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;
...
String myString = null;
System.out.printf("myString: %s",
    ofNullable(myString).orElse("Not found")
);
```

Comment: To apply for also 'empty' values, it can be extended with 'filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())' as the following:
System.out.printf("myString: %s",
    ofNullable(myString).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).orElse("Not found")

Answer (score 48):

For a Java 7 solution that doesn't require external libraries:

```
String.format("this is %s", Objects.toString(this.someField, "?"));
```

Comment: With Java 17 you could use:
"this is %s".formatted("this is %s", Objects.toString(this.someField, "?"))

Answer (score 22):

The nicest solution, in my opinion, is using Guava's Objects method, firstNonNull. The following method will ensure you will print an empty string if someField is ever null.

```
String.format("this is %s", MoreObjects.firstNonNull(this.someField, ""));
```

[Guava docs](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.java).

Comment: `String.format("this is %s", StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(this.someField, ""));` will do the trick if Apache StringUtils happens to be on your classpath.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late on the subject, but this could be a quite clean-looking solution : 
First, create your own format method...

```
private static String NULL_STRING = "?";

private static String formatNull(String str, Object... args){
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if(args[i] == null){
            args[i] = NULL_STRING;
        }
    }

    return String.format(str, args);
}
```

Then, use it as will...

```
@Test
public void TestNullFormat(){
    Object ob1 = null;
    Object ob2 = "a test";

    String str = formatNull("this is %s", ob1);
    assertEquals("this is ?", str);

    str = formatNull("this is %s", ob2);
    assertEquals("this is a test", str);
}
```

This eliminates the need for multiple, hard-to-read, ternary operators.

Comment: ... but implies a dependency on your `formatNull` method.

Comment: Of course!
Unless the case forementionned is specific to some output strategy class, where the method can be defined privately in the strategy itself. Then there would be no depenedency problem. If it is used at many places in the application, then yes it would need to be put in some library / util class.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `replaceAll()`, You can assign a default text(String) for `someField`.

But if some time this may assign `null` again. So you can use validation for that case

```
 this.someField == null ? "defaultText" : this.someField
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid repeating ternary operator you can wrap it in more readable method that will check if your object is `null` and return some default value if it is true like

```
static <T> T changeNull(T arg, T defaultValue) {
    return arg == null ? defaultValue : arg;
}
```

usage

```
String field = null;
Integer id = null;
System.out.printf("field is %s %n", changeNull(field, ""));
System.out.printf("id is %d %n", changeNull(id, -1));
System.out.printf("id is %s %n", changeNull(field, ""));
```

output:

```
field is  
id is -1 
id is
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just do

```
String.format("this is %s", (this.someField==null?"DEFAULT":this.someField));
```

Comment: Again, this is using the ternary operator. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args){
    for (int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        if (args[i]==null) args[i]="";
    }
    return String.format(format,args);
}
```

then  use the method ，ok

Answer (score 3):

From java 7, you can use `Objects.toString(Object o, String nullDefault)`.

Applied to your example: `String.format("this is %s", Objects.toString(this.someField, "?"));`

Answer (score 1):

To keep the original value of `someField` (in case null is a valid value), you can use a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java).

```
String.format("This is %s", (this.someField == null ? "unknown" : this.someField));
```