# Replacing "null"s in java.util.formatter output

Tags: java, string, formatting

I'd like to override the behavior of Java's Formatter to change it's behavior for handling nulls. Right now, whenever it encounters a `null` value, it inserts the string `"null"` in place for the format specifier. I'm trying to instead replace these with the string `"NA"`.

It is insufficient for me to simply loop over my argument list and replace the nulls with `"NA"` strings, since it may be the case that the format specifier I encounter is incompatible with strings. For example, Java allows you to write something like `String.format("%.3f", null)`, but not `String.format("%.3f", "NA")`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make String.format("%s", arg) display null-valued arguments differently from "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404710/make-string-formats-arg-display-null-valued-arguments-differently-from-nu)

Comment: It does not, because that only handles the format specifier `%s`. The second part of my question, starting with "It is insufficient..." more or less mentions the solution in that question